# Bootstrap form doesn't cancel submission when validation failed

Tags: javascript, html, submit, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I'm trying to create a form which will send an email to the user on submit.

The thing is that I used Bootstrap's form template and when I submit it with phone and mail wrong values (phone number even empty), the email is sent anyway (with 200 ok) and a success alert is showing.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate id="paymentForm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    required Feild
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                <label for="lastName">Lasr Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    required Feild
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" value="" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" required>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                please enter a valid mail address
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" value="" name="phone" placeholder="example: 050-1111111" pattern="[0]{1}[5]{1}[0-9]{8}" id="phone" required>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                please provide a valid phone number
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="address"> address</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="" required>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                              please provide your address
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="mb-4">

                        <h4 class="mb-3">payment method</h4>
                        <div class="d-block my-3">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input id="cash" value="cash" value="cash" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required checked>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="cash">cash</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input id="bit" value="bit" value="bit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="bit">Bit</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            please choose method
                        </div>

                        <hr class="mb-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">continue to checkout</button>

                    </form>
```

and here is my js:

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {       
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation')       
        Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

                var radioValue = $('#paymentForm input:radio:checked').val()
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated')
                var orderNumber = generateId();
                var cName = $('#firstName').val() + " " + $('#lastName').val()
                var cEmail = $('#email').val()
                var cPhone = $('#phone').val()
                var cAddress = $('#address').val()
                var cSumToPay = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("totalPrice"));
                var cProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products") || "[]");
                cProducts = cProducts.map(Object.values);                   
                cProducts = cProducts.join(' ');
                console.log(cProducts);
                var templateParams = {
                    order_number: orderNumber,
                    customer_name: cName,
                    products: cProducts,
                    addres: cAddress,
                    phone: cPhone,
                    customer: cEmail,
                    payment_Methode: radioValue,
                    customer_sum: cSumToPay
                };
                emailjs.send('gmail', 'orderconfirmation', templateParams)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
                        alert('Yey! Your email was sent :)');           
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log('error');
                        alert(error);
                    });
                event.preventDefault();
            }, false)
        })
    }, false)

}())
```

I would be thankful if you guys can help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section appears to be your only check for validation:

```
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
```

However, `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` are not going to prevent the code from falling through to the next section. You can do that by including a return at this point

```
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }
```

or you can wrap the rest of your code in the `else` of your conditional

```
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                // your email handling code
            }
```

Note: your `event.preventDefault()` is useful to stop the submit button from performing its default behavior of submitting the form and `event.stopPropagation()` will just keep the event from bubbling up to parent elements (which you likely don't need). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

In any case, you do not need two `event.preventDefault()` calls if you place a single one at the top of your event listener, e.g.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, ok but if I do it with if and else, the submitt just stoped without showing the invalid feedback.

Comment: hoo I just forgot to write the .add(was-validate). Thank you very much!